# Reduce code size of my Express application

Tags: express, webpack, serverless-framework, serverless

I've been using the Serverless framework to deploy my Express application. I used their [Express starter template](https://github.com/serverless-components/express/tree/master/templates/express-starter) but since I've added code, when I try to deploy it says: `Your code size must be less than 200MB.  Try using Webpack, Parcel, or AWS Lambda layers to reduce your code size.`

I've looked everywhere for a way to use Webpack to reduce my code size but have had no luck.

How can I use Webpack to make my code smaller than 200MB? Again, outside of more endpoints, my code is identical to this: https://github.com/serverless-components/express/tree/master/templates/express-starter

Comment: We can help you better if you can post your package.json, serverless.yml, and webpack.config.js.

Answer (score 0):

There are some options possible.

1. check if whats needs to be ignored(PACKAGES) is really ignored.
2. maybe you installed some packages that are taking too much space.

that's the main reasons for something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Let me add also some points.

1. as [@Ethanolle pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66224108/2674877) - clean up your npm dependencies.

   - Include only used dependencies in your lambda build.
   - Take advantage of using npm [devDependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/specifying-dependencies-and-devdependencies-in-a-package-json-file).
2. Consider using the webpack for creating your bundle - [serverless-webpack plugin](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-webpack/)
3. As an alternative for webpack you may get the benefit of using the more precise configuration of Serverless how to manage what to [exclude/include](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/packaging#exclude--include) in a bundle